# iframe uses different sessionid

Tags: php, session

I've got an iframe on 1 of my pages which displays a timer.  It is important that when te session ends and the user comes back the timer must start from 0 again.  This is not working, after troubleshooting I've realized that my Iframe has another sessionid than my other pages.  So if the user logs out and comes back the Iframe continues with the previous sessionid.  What am I doing wrong, how do I get my Iframe to not use it's own session id?  So just to sum it up on timer.php (the Iframe page/2nd page) the session_id() stays the same when logged out and coming back in.  I need it to use the same session information as page1, not it's own.  I hope I explained correctly.

**PAGE1**

```
if ($_SESSION['auth']) {
include 'datalogin.php';
$sessionId = session_id();
$tid = $_SESSION['tid'];
$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
echo "<IFRAME SRC='timer.php?tid=$tid&userid=$userid' WIDTH='100' HEIGHT='50' frameborder='0'></IFRAME>";
```

**TIMPER.PHP**

```
<?php
header('P3P:CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');
session_start();
?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1; ">
</head>
<body>
<?php
session_start();
$sessionId = session_id();
echo $sessionId;
```

Comment: You can try session_name instead of session_id

Comment: If your iframe has different sessionid, it is not served from the same server as your main page. By this I mean server *address*, not physical server. Check the scope of your session cookies.

Comment: Do you really have to use iframe? How about those JavaScript framework like jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

solution #1: you can just use (jquery) ajax instead of iframe (that may not solve your issue, I don't really know why are you using iframe)

solution #2: have you tried using session_name('YOUR_SESSION_NAME_HERE'); on each page after using session_start(); ?

solution #3: you can just pass the php session id as a GET parameter (timer.php?tid=$tid&userid=$userid&sess=" . session_id()) to your iframe (as far as I know that's not so secure, anyway can be a solution in custom cases) then you just do session_id($_GET['sess']); after session_start();